# How to identify the particular td element and hyperlink element in a single cell in jquery

Tags: jquery

Can you please modify my code with above question::

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function(jQ) {
    "use strict";

    //Process each table cell in the roster
    jQ("#wb_i").click(function(event) {
        alert('Hi');
    });
});

<td id="dd" class="dd1">
    <div id="x" class="y"> <a href="aaa" id="m" class="aa" />Test</> </div>
</td>
```

Comment: <td id="dd" class=dd1>
<div id="x" class="y">
<a href="aaa" id="m" class="aa">Test</>
</div>
</td>

Comment: Here goes ... `alert("How to identify the particular td element and hyperlink element in a single cell in jquery")` ... precisely as requested ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
/* code emmitted */
//Process each table cell in the roster
jQ("#wb_i").click(function(event) {
    var tds = jQ(this).find("td"); //will give you all td's
    var links = jQ(this).find("a"); //will give you all hyperlinks in the whole table
    var tdsFromClass = jQ(this).find(".td_class"); //will give you td's with the class "td_class"
});
```

Comment: want to use class name for td and hyper link so what is the code for it

Comment: use ".td_class" to find a element with class "td_class" change the values inside .find:

Comment: How to generate context menu with this code am getting json data dynamically use that only i want show context menu ..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your html is invalid.  Anchor tags must have a closing tag, `<a />` does not work, and `</>` is not even a tag.  `<a href="etc">test</a>` is the correct usage.  Please see [this document for correct syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html)

Secondly, if you want to get the specific td/a of the click event, the following should do what you need:

```
jQ("#wb_i").click(function(event) {
    console.log(jQ(event.target)); //the anchor element(if the anchor was clicked)
    console.log(jQ(event.target).closest("td")); //the td element
    console.log(jQ(event.target).find("a")); //the anchor element(if the div was clicked)
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/zBnC6/1/)

It really depends though on what is clicked in this regard, hopefully my comments in the code are enough.

Comment: Based on hyperlink class name i just want to generate context menu in Jquery Please provide me the sample code

Comment: Ask another question for that.  That aside, I'm not just going to give you free code.  That isn't what this site is about.  It's about helping people with problems they have in _existing_ code.